# Trying to set @published bool to true based on results from an API call

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

Hi first off I'm very new to swift and programing (coming from design field).
I'm trying to update doesNotificationsExist based on posts.count

I'm getting true inside the `Api().getPosts {}`
Where I print the following:

```
print("Api().getPosts")
print(doesNotificationExist)
```

but outside (in the `loadData() {}`) I still get false and not the @Publihed var doesNotificationExist:Bool = false doesn't update.

Please help me out, I would really appreciate some guidance to what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

public class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
    @Published var doesNotificationExist:Bool = false
    
    init() {
        loadData()
        startApiWatch()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        
        Api().getPosts { [self] (posts) in
            self.posts = posts

            if posts.count >= 1 {
                doesNotificationExist = true
            }
            else {
                doesNotificationExist = false
            }
            
            print("Api().getPosts")
            print(doesNotificationExist)
        }
        print("loadData")
        print(doesNotificationExist)
    }
    
    func startApiWatch() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true) {_ in
            self.loadData()
            
        }
    }
```

View where I'm trying to set an image based on `store.doesNotificationsExist`

StatusBarController:

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

class StatusBarController {
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    private var popover: NSPopover
    
    @ObservedObject var store = DataStore()
    
    init(_ popover: NSPopover)
    {
        self.popover = popover
        statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
        statusItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: 28.0)
        
        statusItem.button?.action = #selector(togglePopover(sender:))
        statusItem.button?.target = self
    
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            let itemImage = NSImage(named: store.doesNotificationExist ? "StatusItemImageNotification" : "StatusItemImage")
            statusBarButton.image = itemImage
            statusBarButton.image?.size = NSSize(width: 18.0, height: 18.0)
            statusBarButton.image?.isTemplate = true
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(sender:))
            statusBarButton.target = self
        }
        
    }
`Other none relevant code for the question`

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a ***closure*** and hopefully the `@escaping` one. `@escaping` is used to inform callers of a function that takes a closure that the closure might be stored or otherwise outlive the scope of the receiving function. So, your outside print statement will be called first with bool value false, and once ***timer*** is completed `closure` will be called changing your `Bool` value to ***true***.

Check code below -:

```
import SwiftUI


public class Model: ObservableObject {
    //@Published var posts: [Post] = []
    @Published var doesNotificationExist:Bool = false
    
    init() {
        loadData()
       // startApiWatch()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        
        getPost { [weak self] (posts) in
            //self.posts = posts

            if posts >= 1 {
                self?.doesNotificationExist = true
            }
            else {
                self?.doesNotificationExist = false
            }
            
            print("Api().getPosts")
            print(self?.doesNotificationExist)
        }
        print("loadData")
        print(doesNotificationExist)
    }
    
    func getPost(completion:@escaping (Int) -> ()){
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) {_ in
            completion(5)
            
        }
    }
}

struct Test1:View {
    @ObservedObject var test = Model()
    var body: some View{
        Text("\(test.doesNotificationExist.description)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tushar-sharma that seems to fix the issue with. the bool not being set to true.
All though I seem to still have a problem. I have Edited my question to contain my other file where I'm trying set an image based on the does.NotificationExist

Comment: @NiklasPeterson The updated code you shared is for swift, and not swiftUI. Property wrappers are meant to work with swiftUI views.

Comment: Sorry still very new to programming :D

so I can't use the `@ObservedObject var store = DataStore()` or `let itemImage = NSImage(named: store.doesNotificationExist ? "StatusItemImageNotification" : "StatusItemImage")` in normal swift then?

Comment: You should look at how to communicate between swift and swiftUI. We can still do it, but not in the direct way as you tried.

Comment: I'll accept the answer since it answered my first question. But I'm still not 100% sure how to solve the second part of the problem if I set the `self.doesNotificationExist = true` then it shows shows the right image but with it still doesn't update based on the suggestion you made before.

So the data is passed because if I change it to true it shows right image. It's just don't set the image after the completion(5)

Comment: You are making changes within init, it will not be called once completion(5) is called. We are not creating object again